# What types of files are supported for display by a RichTextBox?

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

I've looked on MSDN, and I am having trouble finding which file types (extensions) can be displayed in a RichTextBox in Winforms.

I have written an app that allows the user to display files from a specific folder based on the user's choice of file extensions. For example only display .txt and .html and ignore anything else.

Therefore, I need an exhaustive list of the extensions that wiil render properly so that I can populate a list for the user to choose from.

I don't suppose it's relevant but I'm using C#.

Any help is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MSDN's documentation, it appears that the `RichTextBox` is only intended to open .rtf files, but can also open plain text (.txt) ASCII and Unicode files using the `LoadFile` method with the `RichTextBoxStreamType` argument.

Sources:

- [RichTextBox.LoadFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d76176b1.aspx)
- [RichTextBoxStreamType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextboxstreamtype.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i guess that's it then, it depends on the encoding as opposed to the file extension. i hoped that there was a list of extensions, but it sounds like the same file extension might work for one encoding but then not another so the list would be useless. Thanks.